# Android login screen with internet connection install error

Tags: android, authentication

I'm working on a login screen in Android which connects to Internet so as to check that the username and the password are correct.

**LoginScreen.java**

```
package com.example.shop;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.example.shop.R;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class LoginPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

    Context context;
    private TextView textView;
    EditText username;
    EditText password;
    String userid;
    boolean succeed;
    Boolean isInternetPresent; 
    ConnectionChecker cc; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
        context=this;
        userid = "";
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_login_username);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_login_password);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        cc = new ConnectionChecker(getApplicationContext());
        isInternetPresent = false;
     //login_button();

        Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
        enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(arg0.getId() == R.id.enter)
            {
                Toast.makeText(
                        context, 
                        "Login correcte", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Tenda.class);
                DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
                task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.v2msoft.com/clientes/lasalle/curs-android/login.php" });
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }

            if (username.getText().toString().equals("luis") && password.getText().toString().equals("seguro")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting...", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                succeed = true;
                userid = "luis";
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong info",
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                succeed = false; 
            }


            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void login ()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";
          for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          textView.setText(result);
        }
      }


    public void login_button()
    {



    }

    public void IC (View v)
    {
        isInternetPresent = cc.isConnectingToInternet();

        // check for Internet status
        if (isInternetPresent) {
            // Internet Connection is Present
            // make HTTP requests
            showAlertDialog(LoginPage.this, "Internet Connection",
                    "You have internet connection", true);
        } else {
            // Internet connection is not present
            // Ask user to connect to Internet
            showAlertDialog(LoginPage.this, "No Internet Connection",
                    "You don't have internet connection.", false);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);       

            // Setting OK Button
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

            // Showing Alert Message
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And my layout:

**activity_login_page**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginPage" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ></TextView>

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittext_login_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:text="username"
        android:inputType="text"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_login_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="password"
        android:password="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_login_username"
         />

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/enter"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="login"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_login_password" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that, when I try to run it with the emulator, I get the following error:

```
12-12 09:24:54.808: E/cutils-trace(5407): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Can anyone help me figure out my mistake?

Comment: what is exactly the problem? does your application crash?

Comment: No. It doesn't install into the emulator. I get that logcat error and I can't open it to begin with. I did search for solutions but I can't seem to find the root of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are using a different name of your layout **activity_login_page**

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
```

but your layout is **activity_login_screen**

change it to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);
```

Comment: Eh, no, it's my mistake: the layout is correct. I put the name wrong in my question. It's correct as it is: else I'd already been notified of that error by Eclipse.